# Dictionary on J file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a dictionary file in javascript shown as such below.

[image]

And I get this below error while running the program.

[image]

Can anybody explain what am I missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your getting error because update__apply is variable which is not defined yet... secondly you sould provide complete code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As @ash says it looks as though update_apply is not defined yet but [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask will help you frame a good question to make it easier for people to help you. In particular giving a minimal piece of code which demonstrates your problem rather than an image helps with testing.

Comment: `update_apply` should be `"update_apply"` in order to use it as key name, and not a variable name, I think that's what you wanted to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing the variable like
`swupdateResponse_dict.update_apply = 0; eel.swupdateResponse(swupdateResponse_dict.update_apply);`
It should fix the issue